# Alexander's theorem (on stellar moves)

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, convex-polytopes

A widely used theorem these days says that given (*abstract*) simplicial complexes $K$ and $K'$, a polyhedron $P\subset R^n$ and homeomorphisms $|K|\to P$ and $|K'| \to P$ which are linear (better to say affine) in each simplex then $K$ and $K'$ are stellar equivalent as abstract simplicial complexes.

Therefore we have a sequence:

$$K \to K_1 \to K_2 \to K_3 \to \dots \to K_n\to K' $$

of abstract simplicial complexes where $K_{i+1}$ is obtained from $K_i$ by an isomorphism ("vertex name change"), a stellar subdivision or a welding (inverse stellar subdivision).

Question: can you do this in order that each $K_i$ is linearly (as opposed to piecewise linearly) embedded in $P$?

My version of the answer. Looking at the classical references of the proof of Alexander's theorems it does appear that the proofs do not imply this stronger statement: the problem being that sometimes $K_i$ may very well contain the star of a non-convex cell (which my be not "star-shaped") in $P$ and some welds may be not-realizable in $P$ without modifying $P$, slightly, to an isomorphic complex: c.f. L. C. Glaser, Geometrical combinatorial topology volume 1, pages 23 and 29.

PS: Great texts on Alexander's theorem are:
a) The first two chapters of  L. C. Glaser, Geometrical combinatorial topology volume 1.

b) Alexander's original paper: Alexander, James W. The combinatorial theory of complexes. Ann. of Math. (2) 31 (1930), no. 2, 292–320.

c) Lickorish, W. B. R.: Simplicial moves on complexes and manifolds. (English summary) Proceedings of the Kirbyfest (Berkeley, CA, 1998), 299–320 (electronic), Geom. Topol. Monogr., 2, Geom. Topol. Publ., Coventry, 1999.

Comment: Hi Joao, welcom to MO. If you're using "classical references", I suggest you refer to them at the end of your post. This way, future users can use them as well.

Comment: Hi! That is a very good point! Will do.

Answer (score 4):

Correct question. May be this quick recollections are completely false. I was thinking many years ago about it. Seems that this is a matter of arithmetic (!) of vertices of triangulations. It is visionabe when we are understanding triangulations as related to rational (!) fans of toric varieties and actually in rational case it is equivalent to "*weak* factorization conjecture" of equivariant birational isomormism of non-singular toric varietis in a sequence of blowups and blowdowns. This conjecture is supposed to be true.  So generally one should infinitesimally move triangulations  to rational, but this is far from innocent operation. Yo may need to heavily break P and actually a lot of interesting troubles come.
The story was developed around the failure of R. Morelli's proof of Oda-Hironaka *strong* factorisation conjecture, see for last list references here
https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.4693 
These days we have a lot of developments around algebraic geometry, physics and combinatorics of fans related to "Okunkov bodies". So perhaps one can use it for the question in an interesting way.

Comment: I think, the irrationality of vertices is not a problem. The 1996/97 Morelli-Wlodarczyk proof of the weak Oda conjecture actually first shows that you can relate two geometric triangulations by geometric stellar subdivisions and welds, and only after that it shows that if the initial vertices were rational, one can choose all new vertices to be rational as well.

Comment: Oh, certainly one should first check Wlodarczyk's proof of weak factorization

Answer (score 3):

Yes, two triangulations of a polyhedron can be connected by a sequence of *geometric* stellar moves (subdivisions and weldings). And you are right, this does not follow from the Alexander theorem, which deals with *combinatorial* stellar moves. This was proved by [Morelli, The birational geometry of toric varieties J. Algebraic Geom. 5(1996), no. 4, 751–782.] and [Wlodarczyk, Decomposition of birational toric maps in blow-ups & blow-downs, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 349 (1997), no. 1, 373–411.] (They proved also more: if the triangulation is unimodular, then there is a path through unimodular triangulation.)

An outline of Morelli's proof can be found in our article with Jean-Marc Schlenker: [On the infinitesimal rigidity of polyhedra with vertices in convex position](http://msp.org/pjm/2010/248-1/pjm-v248-n1-p10-s.pdf), here is the [arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0711.1981v1.pdf).

Morelli-Wlodarczyk theorem deals with convex polyhedra.
It is not completely clear to me how to extend the theorem to non-convex polyhedra. If we modify the triangulations of the cells in some order, there can appear problems on the boundaries between the cells.

Maybe one can do the following: extend some stellar subdivisions of $K$ and $K'$ to triangulations $\overline{K}$ and $\overline{K'}$ of the convex hull of $P$. A sequence of stellar moves from $\overline{K}$ to $\overline{K'}$ induces a sequence of stellar moves between the stellar subdivisions of $K$ and $K'$. Hence we also have a sequence of moves joining $K$ and $K'$.

Comment: Hi. Do you mean: Theorem 2.2 [Morelli 1996, Włodarczyk 1997]. Any two triangulations of a convex polyhedron $P\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ can be connected by a sequence of geometric stellar moves.

Does this extends to non-convex polyhedra?

Comment: @JoaoFariaMartins Yes. That's indeed not obvious. I add an explanation to my answer.

Comment: It seems we should say  why we can *always* extend triangulation of polyhedron up to triangulation of its convex hull. Can we?

Comment: @NikolaiMnev Right. That might be even false. What would suffice is to extend some stellar subdivision of $K$ to a triangulation of the convex hull of $P$. This should be possible.

Comment: How about that. There is a lemma that for any two triangulations of a polyhedron there is a stellar subdivision of one that refines the second. Now take a triangulation $K$ of $P$ and any triangulation $L$ of ${\mathrm conv}(P)$. I think the argument of that lemma yields a sequence of stellar subdivisions of $K$ that extend to stellar subdivisions of $L$ and finally yield a triangulation of ${\mathrm conv}(P)$ that extends a stellar subdivision of $K$.

Comment: Yes I seems so. Good idea perhaps to fix the statement that from Morelli-Wlodarczyk theorem follows the theorem for arbitrary compact polyhedron.